# Using conda environments in emacs

Tags: python, osx, path, environment

What is the best way to use [conda environmets](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) using emacs as a Python IDE?

I have got different conda environments while programming in Python:

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
django                   /Users/Pablo/anaconda/envs/django
scipy                 *  /Users/Pablo/anaconda/envs/scipy
visual                   /Users/Pablo/anaconda/envs/visual
ml                       /Users/Pablo/anaconda/envs/ml
root                     /Users/Pablo/anaconda
```

But when I use <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> emacs only uses my the Mac OS X default Python PATH. How can I chage it between all the different conda environments?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest using [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) library, it provides a neat interface to selecting a virtual env among several alternatives updating interpreter and library paths. You will need to alter WORKON_HOME variable (it defaults to `$HOME/.virtualenvs` used by virtualenvwrapper).

```
(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "/Users/Pablo/anaconda/envs")
(pyvenv-mode 1)
```

After that choose the environment with <kbd>M-x pyvenv-workon</kbd>.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you! Do you know where can I found more documentation on this matter? I haven't found any information about pyvenv and anaconda, but I added this two lines in my settings file and it's working fine. @immerrr

Comment: On which matter? On writing configs or on pyvenv itself?

Comment: To switch between python3 and python2, I had to issue `(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")` or `(setq python-shell-interpreter "python2")`

Comment: A bit more robust way of doing this is `(setenv "WORKON_HOME" (concat (getenv "CONDA_PREFIX") "/envs"))`. This way when you change machines but want to keep your emacs config file consistent.

Comment: I use the first method which means (setenv "WORKON_HOME" "/Users/Pablo/anaconda/envs")
(pyvenv-mode 1)
but when I run my python file, the default env is still used.

Comment: When juggling multiple conda environments, Instead of altering environment variables as this answer suggests, I set the conda environment based on the project I am in via `pyenv-activate` (in my case, setting it to `~/apps/miniconda/envs/my-conda-environment`, though your conda env path will likely differ, see value of `$CONDA_PREFIX` in terminal when env is activated).

Answer (score 8):

I have recently incorporated Anaconda into my python development and was having similar problems setting up Emacs + flycheck + linters.  This answer got me up and running, but I've modified it, since the `conda.el` package is available.  The following will integrate in the Anaconda path and setup Emacs to recognize the currently active Anaconda env.  As a bonus, it updates the Mode line with the env name.

```
;;Anaconda support
(require 'conda)

(setq conda-env-home-directory "<path-to>/anaconda3")
;;get current environment--from environment variable CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
(conda-env-activate 'getenv "CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV")
;;(conda-env-autoactivate-mode t)
(setq-default mode-line-format (cons mode-line-format '(:exec conda-env-current-name)))
```