# Spacemacs use anaconda environment

Tags: spacemacs, python, ipython, anaconda-mode

I have anaconda environments for python2 and python3 as I have code written in the different versions

In spacemacs (with python layer installed), when I open ipython (`SPC m s i`) it starts with my default environment (python 3)

Is there a way to choose which version of python I run my code with? I've tried opening a shell with `activate python2` to activate my other environment, but ipython in emacs still opens with my default

One way I've found is to activate the environment is `SPC m V a` then navigate to the directory where the venv is, but this is quite tedious as the python script and venv are often on different drives so it takes a fair bit of typing/tabbing to get to the venv directory

Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, this is a duplicate of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20092/using-conda-environments-in-emacs). Reproducing the proposed behavior with spacemacs, I changed my `user-init` to:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
  (setenv "WORKON_HOME" "/home/<username>/.local/bin/anaconda3/envs")
)
```

After reloading my `.spacemacs` file with `SPC f e R`, I'm immediately able to use `, V w` and select environments from my anaconda installation.

Comment: `, v w` for me.

Comment: Once I switch conda environments, If I do `SPC m c c` to run my script, it still uses my base environment. Any ideas how to run with the selected environment?

Answer (score 0):

Full process to make running `SPC m c c` inside a conda env work on Windows:

```
# install both layers in the dotfile
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
... add the 2 lines below
(python :variables python-shell-interpreter "c:/path/to/conda/envs/ds/python.exe")
(conda :variables conda-anaconda-home "c:/path/to/conda")
...

# setup pyvenv in user-init
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
... add the 2 lines below
  (setenv "WORKON_HOME" "d:/progs/mambaforge/envs")
  (pyvenv-mode 1)
...
  )

# then open python file and make sure all the modes are active (run them)
python-mode
anaconda-mode
pyvenv-mode

# select environment in pyvenv and conda
pyvenv-workon
conda-env-activate
```

Finally `SPC m c c` runs inside the environment.