# Setting Spacemacs default conda environment

Tags: spacemacs, python

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32103/) answers where spacemacs looks for conda environments and how to change them with `major-mode pyvenv-workon`.

There's one environment that I use for 90% of what I do. Can I set a default environment for the python layer or is it more reasonable to have a init for the python layer that calls pyvenv-workon? I'm new to emacs and spacemacs, so how would I do either of these?

There doesn't appear to be a specific variable in the [python layer](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/python/README.html) and the `dotspacemacs/user-config ()` would run on any layer, so I might not want that. Despite that, what I did was write `(pyvenv-workon "path/to/default/conda")` in the `user-config ()` and it seems to work for python code and likely others, but I'm not sure if it will break anything that relies on the system python.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out while trying to learn git. Since Spacemacs has project management tools, if it identifies the file to be in a project, it will includes a `.dir-local.el` file to set local parameters. Because of the `,Vw` command (which calls `major-mode pyvenv-workon`) my `.dir-locals.el` file looks like,

> ;;; Directory Local Variables
> ;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")
>
> ((python-mode
> (python-shell-virtualenv-root . /home/john/miniconda3/envs/physics)))

So if you're in a project, setting pyvenv values once is enough *if* you've got the file in a project. I'm not sure if Spacemacs recognizes project types other than git, but I think I got it.